# Heroku Postgress Database automatically changed after the upgrade

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

We recently upgraded the plan on Heroku from free. Post this upgrade, our existing database got deleted and Heroku added a new database for the app.

Now we have lost the existing tables and we haven't took a backup for the same. Due to this our app is not connecting.

Is there a way to restore the previous database(PostgreSQL)so that our data will be back and the app will also connect back.

Comment: How did you upgrade? There are [a few options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/updating-heroku-postgres-databases), plus probably some non-recommended processes that aren't listed there. Do you see config vars that look like database credentials with colours in the name, like `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL`?

Comment: Hey, @Chris Thanks for responding. We did the upgrade from Heroku UI itself, as it gave an option for the same once we added our card details. Under the app settings, I can see config vars and it says.  [tag:HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BROWN_URL]